# Unrecognized field: 'ntoreturn' error in documenDB

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I am fetching `Unrecognized field: 'ntoreturn'` error when i try to change page in my aws documentDB. I have used `Robo3t` for connect DocumentDB using SSH tunnel.

[image]

Comment: What tool are you using? Or how can I reproduce the error that you are posting?

Comment: @JosephIdziorek, i have used Robo3t for connect AWS documentDB

Comment: Can you please provide the steps to help me reproduce the error that you are seeing. I am able to connect and query my DocumentDB cluster from Robo3T but need your help on understanding what the 3 fields are and what query or action you took in Robo3T.

Comment: @JosephIdziorek, it's not about that 3 fields, in my collection I have lots of records. when I try to change my page it shows me this error. This error also shows after I delete any record.

Comment: @JosephIdziorek We're getting this error when trying to save an edited document. Appears that that edit did commit however. Worked just fine in previous RoboMongo client editions. Deleting a document also does it.

Comment: @JosephIdziorek, I have used other GUI tools and it's working fine now.

Comment: @JosephIdziorek What tool did you end up using? I'm experiencing the same issue using Robo3T with DocumentDB. Results in being unable to page between results.

Comment: @SkylarGraika, happy to help, can you please help me repro the issues that you're seeing?

Comment: @SkylarGraika i have used nosqlbooster `https://nosqlbooster.com/` you can check this link. it is working quite well with documentDB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chiming in with [Ketan Modi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720771/ketan-modi).

[NoSQLBooster](https://nosqlbooster.com/) free version is an okay replacement for Robo 3T if not exactly a perfect solution. Had the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody else has been having this issue, I had this same error message in version 1.3.1 but upgraded to version 1.4.3 and it appears as though it has been fixed.